# Show that $\int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{\tan(t)}{\sqrt{\cos(2t)}}dt = \frac{\sin^{-1}1/3}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I am aware of half-angle identities as well as the identity $\cos (2t)=\cos^{2}t-\sin^{2}t$ but I'm quite lost on how to proceed.

Comment: Take $u = \sqrt{\cos(2t)}$ and see how far you get (you should get the complete answer provided you recognize the antiderivative of a certain function). If you don't get to the final answer then edit whatever your substitution yielded into this post so that others can complete your attempt and help you see what you did right and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The substitutions $t=\frac{s}{2}$ and $u=\tan(\frac{s}{2})$ simplify the problem.
\begin{gather*}
 \int_{0}^{\pi/6}\dfrac{\tan(t)}{\sqrt{\cos(2t)}}\,\mathrm{d}t=\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/3}\dfrac{\tan(\frac{s}{2})}{\sqrt{\cos(s)}}\,\mathrm{d}s = \\[2ex]
 \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{3}}\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}}\cdot\dfrac{2}{1+u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u = \int_{0}^{1/\sqrt{3}}\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}\,\mathrm{d}u= \\[2ex]
 \dfrac{1}{2}\left[\arcsin(u^2)\right]_{0}^{1/\sqrt{3}} =  \dfrac{1}{2}\arcsin(1/3).
\end{gather*}